# Node.js Express | Always getting null when trying to get a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql

I am very new to node.js and I want to receive on an HTML5 website JSON from a PostgreSQL database. So, on the server side I use node-postgres module for DB connection and also express module for communication. The PostgreSQL query is returning a JSON object.

Server-side:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
   var pg = require('pg');

            var conString = "postgres://postgres:postgres2@localhost/spots";

            var client = new pg.Client(conString);
            client.connect(function(err) {
              if(err) {
                res.send('could not connect to postgres');
              }
              client.query('SELECT * from spots_json where id=3276', function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                 res.send('error running query'); 
                }
                res.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows[0].json));
                client.end();
              });
            }); 
});

    app.listen(3000);
```

Client-side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" ></script>

    <script>

   $.get('http://localhost:3000/data',{}, function(data){
        alert(JSON.parse(data));
   },"json");                  

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/data` on the browser I get:

```
{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-2.994783,43.389217]}
```

So I see that the server is sending the stringified JSON properly, but on the client I always get null data. I must have some misconception.

Comment: It sounds like you're double-encoding it.

Comment: Whats the value of `data` in the client?

Comment: i thought that data was the answered data. I don't understand the code very well as i started programming some weeks ago..how should it be?

Comment: see my answer. "data" has already been parsed by the `$.get` so it is already a JSON object, no need to try and parse it again, just start working with it

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is how my code is so far, for anyone that could help:

serverside

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
   var pg = require('pg'); 

            var conString = "postgres://postgres:postgres2@localhost/spots";

            var client = new pg.Client(conString);
            client.connect(function(err) {
              if(err) {
                res.send('could not connect to postgres');
              }
              client.query('SELECT * from spots_json where id=3276', function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                 res.send('error running query'); 
                }
                res.set("Content-Type", 'text/javascript'); // i added this to avoid the "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html" message
                res.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows[0].json));
                              client.end();
              });
            }); 

});

app.listen(3000);
```

clientside

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"></meta>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" ></script>

    <script>

   $.get('http://localhost:3000/data?callback=?',{}, function(data){
       alert(data.type); 
   },"json");                  

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The client is now executed on `http://localhost:8888/prueba/prueba.html`

Im getting a js with the following Response:

"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-2.994783,43.389217]}"

The Response can be seen in the following screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zi4c5pqnbctf548/pantallazo.png

But now the alert isn't even shown...

I think i need some light with this.

Answer (score 1):

The data is already an object when you get it, not a string. So `JSON.parse` fails because you gave it an object when it was expecting a string. To verify, change

```
alert(JSON.parse(data));
```

to

```
alert(data.type);
```

and you should get "Point"

The reason you already have an object is because of the `"json"` parameter you provided to `$.get`. If you change that to `"html"` you will get a string back instead which you could then parse out into a JSON object.

Comment: thanks for your explanation chiliNUT. I understand. But i tried both ways and i still get null data...

Comment: i get the following error in Chrome's javascript console:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/data. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. prueba.html:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: hmm. it might be that it is somehow violating the same domain policy. are both the html file and the node.js file on localhost?

Comment: yes, both. I am reading that maybe adding callback to the url works

$.get('http://localhost:3000/data?jsoncallback=?',{}, function(data){
        alert(data.type);
   },"json");

But now i get: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/data?jsoncallback=jQuery19107578904065303504_1383776794489&_=1383776794490". 

I don't know if iam going forward or not...

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you. I think you should unnaccept my answer to see if someone else can give you a better answer, or maybe you should post another question

Comment: Sorry for the late response. There are various ways of getting around CORS. But using chrome the easiest I find is using this tool: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not try to stringify your result when you put it in the response object.
Just put it entirely it will automaticaly that way :

`res.set("Content-Type", 'application/json');
res.json(result.rows[0].json);`

That is the right way to send information through REST APIs.

Then in your client side code, I don't know how it works but it should accept json natively.